# Изменить объект, на который указывает ссылка

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

У Скотта Мейерса написано:

> Если да, это подрывает основы, потому что *C++ не позволяет изменить объект, на который указывает ссылка*.

Вопрос: почему приведенный далее код работает в VS2017?

```
int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int& r = i;

    r++;

    int j = 20;
    r = j;

    i = 5;

    int& r2 = r;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведите цитату в контексте. Выдранная цитата без кода и контекста не имеет смысла. Мэйерс не мог привести подобный текст, к такому коду.

Comment: наверное константная ссылька имелась ввиду

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Все проще - вы читаете фразу "изменить **объект**" как изменить значение объекта, а имеется в виду - изменить ссылку так, чтобы она указывала на другой объект...

Comment: @Harry,  да, я прочитал  поверхностно, но в любом случаи по цитате непонятно что имеется ввиду

Comment: Вспомнилось - *Знаменитый ученый в интервью: «Все мои суждения бессмысленны, если они вырваны из контекста».
На следующий день в газете: «Великий ученый признался, что все его суждения бессмысленны».*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы натолкнулись на этот текст [тут](http://www.plam.ru/compinet/yeffektivnoe_ispolzovanie_c_55_vernyh_sposobov_uluchshit_strukturu_i_kod_vashih_programm/p6.php). Но там речь идет о совсем другом - присваивании двух переменных, которые являются объектами класса, в которых имеется член-ссылка.

И вопрос о том, что при этом должно происходить со ссылкой. В контексте имеется в виду не то, что нельзя изменять сам объект через ссылку, а то, что ссылка не может по ходу дела вдруг начать указывать на другой объект.

С++ не позволяет никак менять значение самой ссылки, а не объекта, на который он указывает. Ссылка, в отличие от указателя, не может сначала указывать на объект `a`, а потом вдруг на объект `b`. Только на один и тот же объект - тот, которым она инициализирована - все время своего существования.

Так понятнее?

Да, фраза переведена несколько двусмысленно, не спорю...

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, Вы не так поняли, что имел ввиду Мейерс. Изменение объектов, на которые указывают ссылки -- вполне возможное действие. Например, когда мы передаем объект в функцию по ссылке.
В вашем коде когда вы оперируете с `r`, вы на самом деле оперируете с объектом, находящимся по адресу, который принадлежит `i`, и изменяете значение переменной `i`. Т.о. `int & r = i;` является "псевдонимом" для переменной `i`, как когда мы передаем объект в функцию по адресу (по ссылке, например).